# how to listen the GoogleMap drag and get the center screen lat long in flutter like Ola, Uber

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

Like Ola, Uber, i need to take lat_long from a pin placed in the center of the screen in flutter GoogleMap.
i got the map and i know how to take address from lat_long.
help me with the drag listener part...

here's the code

```
GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          compassEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0,0.0)),
        ),

void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
mapController = controller;
mapController.addListener(_onMapChanged);
refresh(); <----gps function that works fine and cool
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after update (google_maps_flutter ^0.5.7)

```
GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(28.556160, 77.100281)), // INDIA
            onCameraMove: ((pinPosition) {}),  // <-----pinPosition gives LatLong
          ),
```